# Custom GroupRow rendering (mbrn/MaterialTable) React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table, material-table

I am customizing groupRow of mbrn/material-table, But I don't find any documents for doing it.

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/grouping

[image]

So far I managed to make the groupRow and its working fine. But now I don't know how to render the table row on expanding the groupRow.

I tried using `MTableBody` but the records are not showing up

[image]

```
 <tr className="MuiTableRow-root">
    <td
      className="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-alignLeft MuiTableCell-paddingNone MuiTableCell-body py-2"
      colSpan={visiblecolumns + isGroupedAndHidden}
    >
      <button className="d-flex Card w-100">
        <div className="ml-3 text-left">
          <div className="text--bold text--muted text--xs">
            {props.groups[0].title}
          </div>
          <div className="pt-1 pb-1">
            {groupheader.title == 'Priority' ? (
              <Priority value={groupData.value} />
            ) : groupheader.title == 'Time' ? (
              <DateFormatter value={groupData.value} relative={true} />
            ) : (
              groupData.value
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="ListGroupHeader__meta d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
          <span className="ListGroupHeader__count ml-3 mr-1">
            {alerts.length}
          </span>{' '}
          alert{alerts.length > 1 ? 's' : ''}
          <ChevronRight
            className="text-muted"
            style={{ fontSize: '30px' }}
          />
        </div>
      </button>
      <MTableBody {...props} />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

This is how my code looks like. Am so confused I don't know what am missing to make it work

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-bell-5d76e

Comment: Can you set a codesandbox.io example so we can see the whole picture?

Comment: Code SandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-bell-5d76e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided by your reference, the documentation say

> You can override grouped row component with overriding `components.GroupRow`

That's exactly what you did, you overrated the entire component, but that component had a lot of functionality that you've missed like the Expanding and showing the content of the group.

This is the original component - https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/components/m-table-group-row.js

So what you had do is copy and change or create your own component with the same functionality.

In the next example, I took the original component and changed it according to your structure (this is far from perfect, just showing you the way).
I copied MTableGroupRow and MTableCell (because Cell component is part of TableRow and had to change) and called them CustomGroupRow and CustomCell.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-forest-su2dl